# How to change a cell colour based on input of 3 other cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am looking to create a conditional format for a name for when 3 columns (E,F,G) all display the value of "Y". I have tried following a similar query from within StackExchange but i get a return of "The value you entered isn't valid"

The code is here and would appreciate any help.

```
=IF($E$120="Y",1,0),IF($F$120="Y",1,0)IF($G$120="Y",1,0)
```

I have currently the code of this which returns what I want to happen with the name, but is onl based on the "Y" of column E.

```
=IF($E$120:$G$120="y",1,0)
```

Comment: Should be easy using `COUNTIF()` function --> `=COUNTIF($E120:$G120,"Y")=3`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Thank you - That's sorted it!

Comment: You can also use `=AND($E$120:$G$120="y")`

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you would count the number of occurrences and compare this with 3: just count that number of occurrences and use a 2-colour scale based conditional formatting, this gives you the following result:

[image]

Comment: Nice Idea!!! =)

Comment: Because I'm not trying to count how many columns show "Y", it was more of a checklist that when it had been completed in all columns, it was mark the name as completed so @MayukhBhattacharya answer was the correct one for me :)